# JavaScript object.hasOwnProperty() with a dynamically generated property

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hasownproperty

I have an object that I am passing to a function, that I am trying to figure out if the property exists or not, and when it doesn't, ignore it.

The problem is I keep getting `false` even when the property is there. For sake of example, I will use an object I posted on another question earlier today...

```
var myObj = {
       something1_max: 50,
       something1_enabled: false,
       something1_locked: true,
       something2_max: 100,
       something2_enabled: false,
       something2_locked: true,
       something3_max: 10,
       something3_enabled: true,
       something3_locked: true
    }
```

which gets passed to a function like: `buildRetentionPolicyStr('something2', myObj);`

So far I’ve got everything I need with this function working perfectly. Until I tried it on live data and realized on the occasion, properties I thought were static and there with defaults otherwise aren't always actually there. So I need to do something I assume with `hasOwnProperty()` somehow. So in my function I can set a default of my own where if the property exists, use it..

I.e.:

```
function buildRetentionPolicyStr(theScope, obj)
{
   var myVar = 0;
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(theScope + '_enabled'))
   {
       myVar = obj[theScope + '_enabled'];
   }
}
```

In my current test case, the object does in fact exist, so I know that to be true. However, when I do (right above the *if* statement):

```
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(theScope + '_enabled'));
// Or
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty([theScope + '_enabled']));
```

I get this output respective to the order above:

```
false
// Or
["something2_enabled"]
```

What is, if there is one, the proper way to check to see if the property exists in this fashion?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (http://jsfiddle.net/csFfk/) and `hasOwnProperty` is indeed the way to check whether a property exists. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Yea, after playing around.. I did a review top to bottom, and somewhere along the way I crossed the paths, and ended up flipping object references around. So even though the case was true, the code was looking at the wrong object. I am just that special...

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do that is to run `typeof` against your property:

```
obj = { xxx: false }

typeof obj.xxx // 'boolean'
typeof obj.yyy // 'undefined'
```

Comment: Now, while this is a good answer for some measure. It doesn't apply to mine specifically. Just because I used the enabled true/false in the example, doesn't mean I wouldn't use the _max as well for other things. In the end, it turns out `obj.hasOwnProperty([theScope+'_max'])` is actually the proper way. I just messed myself up somewhere else and cause of that things were mix matching, and coming back false.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a review of my code to figure out overall that I had some mix matched cases. While I was in all doing what I should have, I overwrote one of my variables and caused the object I was looking for to essentially to end up going missing. So in fact `false` was correct.

So to verify the how or which was proper for me in my case.

`obj.hasOwnProperty([theScope+'_enabled']);`

was the proper way.

Comment: No, remove the array literal! You're supposed to pass a plain string (the array only works because it yields the same when being stringified)